# Username and pass required in "git push appengine master"

Tags: php, git, google-app-engine, git-push

This is my first time using Google App Engine. I am trying to upload a PHP website. I am trying to upload it using git. I have followed their tutorial. At the end they said to type this code in so i did. I have tried to type this code in git bash.

Here is the code - `git push appengine master`. It then asks me about a username and password. Nowhere in the tutorial said anything about any username or password. I have tried to give it my Google email-id and password but it said authentication failed. I don't know what to do now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generate your password for deployment in **Cloud Console**.

Go to [cloud.google.com/console](https://cloud.google.com/console), select your project, and on the left menu list, expand *Cloud Development*, and click on *Push-to-deploy*.

An alternate way to get there is from the **App Engine console**, under *Admininstration*, in *Application Settings*, in the *Source Push-to-Deploy* section, by following the link that says *click here*.

I assume you already know this since you have successfully set up the repo.

Now, once you're in Push-to-deploy settings, you'll see a <kbd>Get password</kbd> and a <kbd>Delete repository</kbd> button at the top. Obviously, you need the former.

[image]

You'll have to go through Google's OAuth authentication, select the account that is a developer account in your application, and click <kbd>Accept</kbd> to grant read-write access to **Google Code**.

Once you grant access, you'll see a page saying:

> This is your git password:
>
> …
>
> To use this password, please add the following text to your `.netrc` file:

```
machine code.google.com login you@gmail.com password yourpassword
```

> [Learn more](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/push-to-deploy) about using Git and Push-to-Deploy.

You'll need to copy-paste code in your `.netrc` file, which should in your home directory. If it does not exist, just create it.

### On Windows:

As [eddard.stark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1380626/eddard-stark) mentioned in his comment, *on windows, the `.netrc` file has to be named `_netrc` instead*.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. but the problem is i have done all these. I am in the last part. i have done this part saying "If your development code is not yet a local Git repository, make it one, and link it to the URL of the new Google repository with the following commands:". but when i try to do the next bit saying "git push appengine master". what is my username?

Comment: what is my username? where can i find it? git is asking me for my username of https://code.google.com

Comment: i think git cannot find my .netrc file. but i have set my HOME variable. and the is a .netrc file containing a single line that is "machine code.google.com login my_email@gmail.com password mypassword"

Comment: thank you for all your help. I have solved it. In windows you have to save the .netrc file as _netrc

Comment: @eddard.stark thanks for sharing that! I've updated my answer so that people searching for this can find the solution easily. Frankly, I didn't even know you were on windows.

Comment: The "cloud development / push to deploy" link is not / no longer present on my cloud console. All I can find now about push-to-deploy uses jenkins / maven / gradle, which I should probably learn some day when I have the time.