# Google App Engine Repository through Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, egit, google-plugin-eclipse

I have a Google App Engine project, which I can commit and push to the GAE repository (not a github repository) using gcloud command line.

Since I am using eclipse, I attempted to use EGIT setting up my GAE repository URL as a remote. When I use egit to commit and push, I am prompted for a username and password- my google username and password do not work.

I am having trouble finding help for this particular situation- it seems I either need to use the command line to commit and push, or sign up for a github account...

Config details:

```
default/.git$ cat config
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[credential]
    helper = gcloud.sh
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://source.developers.google.com/p/{APP ID}/r/default
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

If EGIT will not work properly with Gcloud authentication, is there a plugin that WILL? I figured that since google provides plugins for gcloud development in eclipse, that they might support their own repository system...

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please include the contents of `.git/config` in your question?

Comment: robinst .git/config added! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JGit (the Git implementation that EGit uses) doesn't support this part of your Git configuration as of now:

```
[credential]
    helper = gcloud.sh
```

It looks like you have to generate a separate password, see the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20411101/305973). In Eclipse, you then should be able to store the username and password in the secure storage.

Comment: Unlike the user in that question, I am able to do the git push from the command line. However, not from egit plugin for eclipse. only in eclipse/egit am i asked for a username and password. any thoughts?

Comment: Did you maybe add the username and password to your `~/.netrc`?

Comment: When I do the git push from the command line, it doesn't ask for password. I believe it is using OAuth2, which was set up using the "gcloud auth login" command, so it never prompts me for a password. ~/.netrc doesn't seem to exist on my filesystem.

Comment: Looks like gcloud uses `credential.helper`, which JGit does not support. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks robinst for that extremely useful piece of info! Do you happen to know what plugin/software google intends developers to use, or recommend a plugin that might work better?

Comment: I would hope that they intend developers to use whatever they want on the client side ;).

Comment: Sure.. I don't disagree. I'm just having trouble finding the tool that supports Google's repositories! It just "feels" like I'm trying to do things the hard way, as in not how Google envisioned the typical workflow. I'm going to try Android Studio next. Thanks again for your input!